# how can i fix the undefined error in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hy , i am stuck at the last part were i have to write the place marker(place_marker(the_Board, player2_marker, position)) , it doesn't recognize the marker , it said it is a undefined variable , any ideas ?

Here is my script : (it isn't finished yet because of that problem )

```
def display_board(board):
    print('\n'*3)
    print(board[7]+'|'+board[8]+'|'+board[9])
    print(board[4]+'|'+board[5]+'|'+board[6])
    print(board[1]+'|'+board[2]+'|'+board[3])

#test_board = ['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X'] #test
#display_board(test_board) #test

def player_input():
    print('\n'*3)
    Player1_name=input('What is your name player1 ? : ')
    Player2_name=input('What is your name player2 ? : ')
    marker = ''
    while marker != 'X' and marker != '0' :
        Player1=marker = input('{}, please chose X or 0 : '.format(Player1_name))

    if Player1 == 'X':
        Player2 = '0'
    else:
        Player2= 'X'


    return ('OK, {} is : {}\nAnd {} is : {} ' .format(Player1_name,Player1,Player2_name,Player2))

#print(player_input()) #test

def place_marker(board, marker, position):
    board[position] = marker

#print(place_marker(test_board,'2',8))
#print(display_board(test_board))

def win_check(board, mark):
    return ((board[7] == mark and board[8] == mark and board[9] == mark) or (board[4] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[6] == mark) or (board[1] == mark and board[2] == mark and board[3] == mark) or (board[7] == mark and board[4] == mark and board[1] == mark) or (board[8] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[2] == mark) or (board[9] == mark and board[6] == mark and board[3] == mark) or (board[7] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[3] == mark) or (board[9] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[1] == mark))

#print(win_check(test_board,'X')) #test

import random 

def choose_first():
    flip = random.randint(0,1)
    if flip == 0 :
        return 'Player1'
    else:
        return 'Player2'

def space_check(board, position):
    return board[position] == ''

def full_board_check(board):
    for i in range(1, 10) :
        if space_check(board, i):
            return False
    return True

def player_choice(board):
    print('\n'*3)
    position = 0
    while position not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or not space_check(board,position):
        position = int(input('Please chose a position from 1 to 9 : '))
    return position

def replay():
    choise = input('Do you wnat to play again, yes or no ? : ')
    return choise == 'yes'

print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!')
while True:
    the_board=[' '] *10
    player_input()
    turn=choose_first()
    print(turn+'will go first')

    play_game=input('Ready to play ? y or n ? : ')
    if play_game == 'y' :
        game_on = True
    else:
        game_on = False 

    while game_on :
        if turn == 'Player1' :
            display_board(the_board)
            position=player_choice(the_board)
            place_marker(the_Board, player2_marker, position)   ### HERE

            if win_check (the_board ,Player1) :
                display_board(the_board)
                print('{} has Won !!')
                game_on = False

        if not replay() :
            break
```

here is the console after i run the code , it don't recognize the number i thick because the final script isn't done ,

```
Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!
What is your name player1 ? : SALLY
What is your name player2 ? : Sammy
Player1will go first
Ready to play ? y or n ? : y
 | | 
 | | 
 | | 
Please chose a position from 1 to 9 : 1
Please chose a position from 1 to 9 : 2
Please chose a position from 1 to 9 : 3
```

it is still asking me for a number

i have tried to change some parameters of the place_marker code but it didn't work

```
def place_marker(board, marker, position):
    board[position] = marker
place_marker(the_Board, player2_marker, position)
```

Comment: I didn't read through that wall of code, but an "undefined variable"error  means an undefined variable. All you have to do is to define that variable before trying to access it

Comment: Why is the function containing only `return board[position] == ''` called `space_check` when the check is for an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is exactly where you mark it:

```
place_marker(the_Board, player2_marker, position)
```

This is the first reference to `player2_marker`. You need to initialise it somewhere before you reference it! I assume this is as simple as setting it to 'O' or 'X' in your case.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer , i realize that , i compared my script with the course solution script and i saw that i made a modify at player input , that was just returning that formatted sentence, so i change my code with that one which return 'x' , '0' or '0', 'x' , that is assigned to the player 1,player 2 = player_input() , i meat player 1 = x and player 2 = o or reverse , so that variable i can introduce in the place_marker function as X (assigned to player 1) or O (assigned to player 2 ) , also little mistakes , and it finally works now !!

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for your answer , i realize that , i compared my script with the course solution script and i saw that i made a modify at player input , that was just returning that formatted sentence, so i change my code with that one which return 'x' , '0' or '0', 'x' , that is assigned to the player 1,player 2 = player_input() , i meat player 1 = x and player 2 = o or reverse , so that variable i can introduce in the place_marker function as X (assigned to player 1) or O (assigned to player 2 ) , also little mistakes , and it finally works now !!